Flutter - Preventing scrolling when gesturing on certain container inside CustomScrollView
child: CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 2.5, left: 2.5),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TestingWIdget(),
            Container(height: 300, width: 300, child: GoogleMapWidget()), // when user touching this, i want to prevent from the page scrolling
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
),

Basically, I want to prevent the Scaffold from scrolling when user is doing something on the Container because it has GoogleMap. When users doing something, the map also moves around. Which I do not want to. I could only find information about IgnorePointer widget but it was just ignoring touching the GooglaMap().
Is there any way to prevent scrolling when users doing something on the certain widget?

Track if the user is interacting with GoogleMapWidget using listener to update CustomScrollView's physics accordingly.
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _isInteractingMap = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      physics: _isInteractingMap
          ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
          : const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      slivers: [
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Listener(
            onPointerDown: (_) {
              setState(() {
                _isInteractingMap = true;
              });
            },
            onPointerUp: (_) {
              setState(() {
                _isInteractingMap = false;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 300,
              child: GoogleMapWidget(),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

